# IChangeSetItemAuthorizer in RESTier 1.0

Tags: restier

Can anyone point me to an example project using IChangeSetItemAuthorizer for custom authorization in RESTier 1.0.

Comment: +1 - did you get anything back on this or find decent information elsewhere? I've tried implementing according to the documentation at http://odata.github.io/RESTier/, but it doesn't appear to work as described.

Comment: Sorry @Jeff nothing, would love to know what happened to the OData team no progress on RESTier in six months

Answer (score 2):

Couple months after the fact, but I just came across this issue yesterday. You need to change the access modifier from `protected` to `public`.

So in their example it would change from this:

```
protected static new IServiceCollection ConfigureApi(Type apiType, IServiceCollection services)
{
    return EntityFrameworkApi<TrippinModel>.ConfigureApi(apiType, services)
        .AddService<IChangeSetItemAuthorizer, CustomizedAuthorizer>();
}
```

To this:

```
public static new IServiceCollection ConfigureApi(Type apiType, IServiceCollection services)
{
    return EntityFrameworkApi<TrippinModel>.ConfigureApi(apiType, services)
        .AddService<IChangeSetItemAuthorizer, CustomizedAuthorizer>();
}
```